# Get Reference of Dialog in onClick

Tags: android, customdialog

I am creating a Custom Dialog on click of a button in my activity. There is button in the Dialog and I have set it like this:

```
 Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePicture);
 buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
```

My Activity is implementing the `onClickListener`, and the overridden `onClick` method looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonTakePicture:
                Dialog dialog = //Get the dialog somehow from view;
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                takePicture();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am struggling to get the Dialog Reference here. I have tried (Dialog)view.getParent() as well as (Dialog)view.getParent.getParent(), but they are not the Dialogs.

> I don't want to have a Dialog Field in my Activity unless it is the only way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not the correct way to do it you have to write a interface in your dialog class and then implement that interface in your activity.

Comment: @Sac Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @sumit is it possible to get the reference of the dialog in onClick itself using the view which is basically our button.

Comment: @Sac u can use the interface for it..

Comment: @Sac so what you want is just the click event from your dialog to your activity. right??

Comment: I want the dialog's reference in the onClick of a button which is part of Dialog.

Comment: @Sac did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solution for this ,

```
Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setTag(dialog);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and get the Dialog like this,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonTakePicture:
                Dialog dialog = (Dialog) view.getTag();
                if (dialog != null) {
                    view.setTag(null);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                takePicture();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Crafty Solution!